# How to pass a ini script and a exe setup in inno script

Tags: inno-setup, ini, pascalscript

```
procedure InstallNetTime(); Forward;   
procedure CreateNTPRegistryEntries(); Forward;        


procedure InstallNetTime();  
begin   

    if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32,'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NetTime_is1') then  
    begin         
       exit;  
    end;

    ShowStatusMessage('Installing NetTime...');     
    CreateNTPRegistryEntries();   
    ExtractTemporaryFile('NetTime-2b7.exe');   
    RunProcess('{tmp}\NetTime-2b7.exe', '');    
 end;

procedure CreateNTPRegistryEntries();     
begin      
     RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys ( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective            Software\NetTime');  
     RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'Hostname', '127.0.0.1');      
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'Protocol', 2);  
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'Port', 37);  
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'SyncFreq', 600);      
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'LostSync', 7500);  
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'WarnAdj', 120);  
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'Retry', 600);      
     RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Subjective
 Software\NetTime', 'Server', 1);   
 end;
```

I have to do a silent installation that's why I'm using inno scripts.
I am using a ini file for the extra information and calling a `RunProcess()` method to pass this ini file as a parameter. First I am extracting the setup and ini file then calling the `Runprocess()` method, like below:

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('ntp-setup-win32.exe');
ExtractTemporaryFile('MeinBergNTP.ini');
RunProcess('msiexec', AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ntp-setup-win32.exe')) 
  + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MeinBergNTP.ini'))
  + ' /quiet /norestart');
```

The second and third lines are executing as i can see the entries of setup into registry. But `RunProcess()` method is not working here. Installer just skips this step. I don't have much idea that how to pass the arguments and exe file together as i am new to Inno Scripts and not finding enough docs on it. Please help me out that how should I use the `RunProcess()` method. Or How can I silent install using the `RunProcess()` method.

Comment: There's no `RunProcess` function in Inno Setup. If it is your user-defined function, we need to see its code to help you.

Comment: Anyway, why are you using `msiexec` to run a `.exe` file? The `msiexec` is for running `.msi` files. You should run `.exe` directly.

Comment: This is code I am using for the installation of a exe setup using RunProcess() method and Its working fine without any parameters. It is not user-defined. I have  checked all of the related iss files, they all are using RunProcess() or RunProcessHidden() kind of functions, those are not user defined. I need to call RunProcess() pasing the ini file as parameter.

Comment: No, there's no `RunProcess` function in IS. It has to be user-defined. Also your new code `RunProcess` call is different to the first code you have posted. Voting to close your question as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RunProcess()` function doesn't exist in Inno Setup (by default), unless you create it yourself.

You might solve the problem by using [Exec](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).

First argument is the file to execute. The second argument is the params to pass to it.

```
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  // Launch installer and wait for it to terminate
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ntp-setup-win32.exe'),
          ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MeinBergNTP.ini') + ' /quiet /norestart',
          '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    // handle success
  end 
  else begin
    // handle failure
  end;
end;
```

---

> Thanks for the reply. But I need to use RunProcess() as all other iss files are using this method only. With exec() method its working fine though :).

You could write a wrapper function.

**RunProcess()**

Build a wrapper function `RunProcess()` around `Exec()`, which accepts the Executable and its Parameters.

```
function RunProcess(Executable: String, Parameters: String): Integer;
var 
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec( ExpandConstant(Exectuable),
          ExpandConstant(Parameters),
         '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    Result := ResultCode;
end;
```

Usage:

```
RunProcess('{tmp}\ntp-setup-win32.exe', '{tmp}\MeinBergNTP.ini /quiet /norestart');
```

**RunProcessHidden()**

Well, there are a lots of ways to hide the exec:

- You could try switching the value for the ShowCmd parameter of the `Exec()` function to `SW_HIDE`.
- Or you could invoke your executable through `start /b ...`. Check `start /?` for its options.
- Or you could also insert a little helper tool, like `RunHiddenConsole.exe` or `HideExec.exe` into your installer and then invoke your executable through that.

  1. Include the helper tools

     ```
     [Files]
     Source: RunHiddenConsole.exe; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
     ```
  2. Extract

     ```
     // extract unzip util from the compressed setup to temp folder and define a shortcut
     ExtractTemporaryFile('RunHiddenConsole.exe');
     hideConsole := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\RunHiddenConsole.exe');
     ```
  3. Add wrapper function RunProcessHidden() to invoke the tool with Command parameter

     ```
     // Run an external command via RunHiddenConsole
     function RunProcessHidden(Command: String): Integer;
     var
         ErrorCode: Integer;
     begin
        if Exec(hideConsole, ExpandConstant(Command), '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then
        begin
            Result := ErrorCode;
        end
        else
        begin
           Log('[Error] ExecHidden failed executing the following command: [' + ExpandConstant(Command) + ']');
           Result := ErrorCode;
        end;
     end;
     ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to use RunProcess() as all other iss files are using this method only. With exec() method its working fine though :).

Comment: I've updated my answer and added examples for wrapper functions to `Exec()`.

Comment: I am using                                                                            TmpFileName1 := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\ntp-setup-win32.exe';
TmpFileName2 := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\MeinBergNTP.ini';  Cmd2 := TmpFileName1 + ' /USEFILE=' +  TmpFileName2; Exec('cmd.exe', '/S ' + Cmd2  , '', SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);                                                                                                    Its working fine. As silently its calling cmd and installing the setup. But in RunProcess() its not doing silently but opening a command prompt.

Comment: /S is probably the silent mode switch for the setup exe, combined mit SW_HIDE. Glad you solved it!

Comment: How can i pass these args in RunProcess method. As command of silent installation is :  ntp-setup-win32.exe /USEFILE=C:\MeinBergNTP.ini

Comment: I've already posted an usage example. But again: RunProcess accepts two strings, first string exe, second string params -  its: `RunProcess('{tmp}\ntp-setup-win32.exe', '/S /USEFILE=C:\MeinBergNTP.ini');`. Both strings are handled by ExpandConstant before Exec takes place, so you can use `{tmp}` in there.